# replay all the transactions from genesis block in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

As we know, the chain of blocks leads to the latest world state. Let's say, a peer uses couchdb to store world state, and someday the couchdb encounters some problem, e.g. someone delete some world state data from it mistakenly so the data is corrupted.

The question is: how to restore the world state based on all blocks from genesis block? How to replay all the transactions from genesis block? Is their any manual way? It seems that Fabric official documentation doesn't mention enough information about this topic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete the state database, when the peer starts up it will detect this and rebuild the state.

Comment: So the replay of blockchain can't be manual. It's automatic. Right?

Comment: You would not manually replay the transactions if that is what you are asking?

Comment: I just want to check whether manual replay is possible or not from technical point of view. You mentioned in case of corrupted couchdb, peer starts up and it will detect it and rebuild the state. But what if the "rebuild state" fail?

Comment: You can always delete everything including the ledger, rejoin channels and then the peer will reprocess all blocks from the orderer ... I'm not sure what you mean by "manually"

Comment: Thanks. You mean that I can delete all the databases(couchdb or goleveldb) related to channel and chaincode, rejoin channels, and peer will reprocess all blocks from the first block to the latest block, and rebuild the databases, right?

Comment: Yes ... exactly

Comment: @GariSingh, when you mention the peer will reprocess all blocks from the orderer to rebuild the world state, does the peer get blocks from anchor peers from other Orgs too (via gossip protocol)?

Comment: It depends on how things are set up; if you are using gossip within an org and the peer is not the leader, it will try to get blocks from other peers in the org.  If it's the leader, it will try the orderer first.

Comment: What if I want to replay the transactions onto other network which has same node/identity certificates but cannot talk to the source network.